# Программный код ученика

Tags: php, mysql

Задание: Найдите ошибки.

```
<?php
 $MV = mysql_connect("localhost", 'igolka97', '******')
if(!mysql_select_db("igor",$MV)){
    die();
}
$queryID="SELECT MAX(id) FROM `tovari` ";
$u=mysql_query($queryID,$MV);
$i=1;
while($i<=$u) {
$queryNAME="SELECT name FROM `tovari` WHERE id=$i";
$queryOPISANIE="SELECT opisanie FROM `tovari` WHERE id=$i";
$queryCENA="SELECT cena FROM `tovari` WHERE id=$i"
        $name=mysql_query($queryNAME,$MV);
        $opisanie=mysql_query($queryOPISANIE,$MV);
        $cena=mysql_query($queryCENA,$MV);  
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><td>".$name."</td><td>".$opisanie."</td><td>".$cena."</td></tr>";
$i++;
}
mysql_close($MV);
?>
```

Comment: а какое задание было дано ученику? а то может задание было найти квадратуру кругу...

Comment: @KoVadim, вы хоть поняли что написали?

Comment: Кстати, автор, а проверить данный код на работоспособность не судьба? Или он не вернул никаких ошибок, что вы его выложили на всеобщее обозрение. Или же выбило кучу ошибок (а так оно и было) и вы не поняли что они значат, и решили дать местным кодерам "задание" что бы исправили ваш код? Я прав?

Comment: Ну исправят раз, исправят два - больше не исправят =)

Да и далеко не уплывет на чужих исправлениях

Comment: Я протестировал и если бы у меня браузер не выдал белый лист  я бы даже не открывал новую вкладку на хешкод

Comment: жжешь аффтар :DDD

если бы у меня **браузер** не **выдал белый лист**

Comment: ну тогда напишите

    error_reporting(E_ALL); 
в начале страницы, откроете много нового для себя :D

Comment: И да, совсем забыл добавить - не называйте так поля таблицы, сейчас возникает такое впечатление что код писал бывший 1Сшник

Comment: @Emile. Я то понял. А для тех кто не понял - там был сарказм:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблемы/ошибки/замечания:

1. Кто сказал, что `id` идут по порядку?
2. `$u` содержит ссылку на ресурс, а не число
3. Ужасная организация работы с БД ( `select` в цикле - зачем??? зачем 3 запроса для 3х полей??? )
4. Тег таблицы ( `<table>` ) создаётся в цикле
5. Нет закрывающего тега для таблицы
6. `$name, $opisanie, $cena` содержат ссылки на ресурсы, а не результаты выборки
7. Передавать переменную подключения ( `$MV` ) есть смысл, если у вас несколько одновременных подключений к БД.
8. Нет единого стиля для строк ( кавычки), sql запросов
9. Нет логики в отступах, именах некоторых переменных ( `$u` например )

Я-бы делал, как минимум, так:

```
<?php
  $dbc = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'igolka97', '******' );
  mysql_select_db( 'igor', $dbc) or die( 'no db' );

  $query = mysql_query(
    'SELECT `name`, `opisanie`, `tovari` FROM `tovari` ORDER BY `id` DESC'
  );

  echo '<table>';
  while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ){
    echo ''.
      '<tr>'.
        '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$row['opisanie'].'</td>'.
        '<td>'.$row['cena'].'</td>'.
      '</tr>';
  }
  echo '</table>';

  mysql_close( $dbc );
?>
```

P.S: Переписывание || Написание кода - это исключение, а не правило

Comment: Я солидарен со всеми пунктами...

Наверное легче ответить что в этом коде сделано правильно чем то, что неправильно =)

Comment: Добавлю еще, что закрывать подключение к БД так-же не обязательно.

Comment: Ну закрытие - это ещё более менее стандартная практика)

Comment: Плохой тон, писать запросы в одинарных кавычках (').

Позвольте спросить, а зачем это?

    echo ''.
И вообще зачем соединять строки через . (точку), чем вас не устраивает этот вариант:

    echo '
      <tr>
        <td>'.$row['name'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['opisanie'].'</td>
        <td>'.$row['cena'].'</td>
      </tr>';
И еще, это конечно мнение каждого, кто как хочет, так и фапает, но все же, вместо этого:

    mysql_fetch_array();
в данном случае лучше использовать:

    mysql_fetch_assoc();

Comment: @Elime,

1. Двойные ковычки предполагают разбор содержимого, поэтому использую одинарные
2. Плохой тон? Откуда информация?
3. У вас лишние пробелы попадут на вывод...
4. assoc или array - каждый в состоянии выбрать

Comment: По-поводу кавычек, пишут во многих учебниках. Да и сами подумайте, как лучше, написать запрос:

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tbl` (`field1`,`field2`) VALUES('data1','data2')");

или:

    mysql_query('INSERT INTO `tbl` (`field1`,`field2`) VALUES(\'data1\',\'data2\')');

Кстати, еще рекомендуется операторы писать в верхнем регистре.

Comment: echo '' - что-бы затем экономить на отступах

10 уровень вложенности + echo ( 4 символа + пробел + выравнивание ):
1. при 2х пробельном отступе = 26 пробела
2. при 4х пробельном отступе = 48 пробелов

Comment: @timka_s, Вы, я вижу, знаете толк в извращениях.

----------------------------------------------------
> вы видимо не писали реально сложных конструкций...

возможно

Comment: Лень искать, прздники на носу. уже отдыхаю по сути. Первое что нашел из гугла( без пафоса ) [тыц](http://tulvit.ru/post/162)

"где-то читал об этом, давно было"... Прочитали и поверили... Теперь учите других (людей реально понимающих разницу между одинарными и двойными кавычками) тому что когда-то давно прочитали непонятно где.

В следующий раз, будьте так добры перед такими ИМХО пафосными заявлениями - потрудитесь найти и предоставить пруфф

Comment: > @Elime, В чем проблема писать:
>
>     mysql_query( 'INSERT INTO `tbl` (`field1`,`field2`) VALUES("data1", "data2");' );

Единственная проблема, которую я вижу, в том, что двойные кавычки могут использоваться для строковых констант только в MySQL. При работе с Postgres, MSSQL (и, вероятно, в sqlite) так или иначе придется использовать одинарные кавычки.

Comment: Проблема в том что нет ни одной аргументации не использовать второй вариант. В том случае где чел (специально или не - хз) написал страшный запрос строкой в одинарных кавычках и значения решил тоже заключить в одинарных кавычках...

Тоже самое я могу сделать и с двойными. Самое смешное что никто нормльного ответа не дал. Как минимум 90% ответов от таких же как вы людей не понимающих разницы.

Лично я для рботы с SQL БД использую PDO и там вообще никакого толку нет. А так дело вкуса, что касаеться читабельности - бред. Лично яне могу читать строки в которых заключены переменные (кады их много)

Comment: Констатирую истинность заявления @Ilya Pirogov...

Postgre и MSSQL рассматривают строку в двойных кавычках - как имя столбца/таблицы/бд...

ИМХО: Сие есть печаль, ибо это не интуитивное переопределение поведения... В том-же MSSQL есть квадратные скобки, которые делаю то-же самое ( [my column] ), что, опять-же имхо, логичнее.

P.S: "читать строки в которых заключены переменные" - совершенно согласен...

P.P.S: я приверженец принципов наименьшего удивления ( авто!!!-парсинг строк для замены переменных - это не стандартное поведение )

Comment: Как я уже говорил, господа, вы знаете толк в извращениях. Такого запроса как написал @Ilya Pirogov я еще не видел. Надеюсь не увижу больше.

Answer (score 1):

```
$u = mysql_query($queryID, $MV); // вернет данные типа resource
```

Таким образом:

```
while($i<=$u) {} // отработает не так как планировалось программистом
// целочисленным значением ресурса $u будет его идентификатор а не максимальный id
// таблицы товаров
```

Для того чтобы исправить эту ситуацию надо было написать как-то так:

```
$lastIdData = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($queryID));
$u = $lastIdData['MAX(id)'];
```

Примерно так-же выборку с БД надо обрабатывать везде, соответственно выводить `echo mysql_query('QUERY ...');` - приведет к выводу строки вида `resource #id`

Это с точки зрения синтаксиса... А что касается кода в целом - ужас каких мало.

Ну и, конечно-же - принцып обработки всех записей таблицы это **нечто**...

PS: ну зачем вы людям праздник портите таким кодом? :D

Comment: Ну обрадуйте меня под праздник...
"Ученик" это я... 
Я сижу обложенным книгами по PHP и MySQL и пытаюсь чего то сделать...
И так я просиживаю все Свои каникулы...
P.S. буду рад вам сказать спасибо :D

Comment: Не совсем понял - написать за вас код или что?

Answer (score -1):

3 запроса в цикле... за такое пальцы отрывать надо

Вот как должен был выглядеть данный код:

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", 'igolka97', '******') or die("Ошибка подключения к БД");
$db = mysql_select_db("igor" , $connect)) or die("Ошибка выбора БД!");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tovari`");

while($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$result['name']."</td><td>".$result['opisanie']."</td><td>".$result['cena']."</td></tr>";
}
?>
```

Comment: А алгоритм обработки всех записей вам нравиться что-ли? =)

Comment: мне просто цыклы в глаза бросились..

Comment: Я попробовал но Браузер все равно выдал ошибку...<br>
<a href="www.prodimport.pro/sql.php"></a>

Comment: ошибку в студию

Comment: Если человек на ответ @Elime - пишет, цитирую "Я попробовал но Браузер все равно выдал ошибку", то в любом случае такого горе разраба необходимо отправлять в матчасть... Причем в ооочень глубокую, тут не языки программирования и работу с БД учить надо... Вообщем "Новый @Prikol xD"

Comment: @Elime Рад был бы сам узнать какая ошибка...

Comment: @AlexWindHope, точно-точно :DDDD

ТС, кури матчасть

Comment: @igolka97, напишите в самом начале страницы:

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

Что бы включить показ ошибок.

после *<?php* конечно же

Comment: сразу скажу что на php ни одной строчки не писал, но разве не надо номер порта указывать в строке подключения?

Comment: @Elime Перед тегом <html>? или <?php?

Comment: 2 @Gautama Buddha можно не указывать номер порта... Более того можно не указывать имя хоста( по умолчанию, если не ошибаюсь - `localhost:3306` )